# How to execute blender command on google colab?

Tags: python, blender, google-colaboratory

I have a script to generate images. Unfortunately, I do not have a GPU and everytime I execute it using CPU, the script breaks after some images and throws some error. I was hoping that is there any way to run python scripts from blender background on Google colab.

I have already done the following:

```
!apt install blender
!apt install libboost-all-dev
!apt install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Executing the above command verifies that blender is already installed. Then I try to run python script in blender background:

```
!blender --background --python script.py -- --num_images 100
```

But then I keep getting the following error and nothing happens.

```
src/tcmalloc.cc:283] Attempt to free invalid pointer 0x7f268381e040
```

The runtime type has been chosen as GPU. Does someone know how to fix it?

Thank you!

Comment: [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/124311/935) sets GPU rendering, change that to CPU. If not sharing your script may be helpful.

Comment: @sambler the script execution does not even start. Do you still insist for updating scrript code? Moreover, bpy import is failing on colab.

Comment: Does your script load a blend file? or create the scene? If `import bpy` is failing then you aren't running the script in blender. The tcmalloc.cc the error is coming from is not part of blender, it would appear to be part of gperftools.

Comment: @sambler it loads a blend file.

Comment: When calling `bpy.ops.render.render()` are you passing `write_still=True`?

Comment: @sambler yes. Please refer to the following file for further details [render_images.py](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wTek6lBbkXgAZdWl2oh9yS93GUQE2Qu2)

Comment: It would look to be specific to google collab. Can you run `!blender -b -f 1` to render the default scene? Do you know others that have used blender in google collab? Can you install a copy of blender that was not linked to tcmalloc? Maybe use a google compute instance or a local machine to render sample images, I expect your aim is to feed them into tensorflow.

Comment: @sambler this is the my first time using blender and that too on google colab as my GPU is bricked. Somehow while installing the blender packages, it always uses tcmalloc. Even on trying `!blender -b -f 1` I still am getting the invalid pointer error.

Comment: Hi, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57695293/2684771) suggests permissions may be involved in accessing GPU.

Answer (score 0):

When using blender on Colab, you need to set the `-noaudio` option.

```
!blender -b -noaudio --python script.py
```

References: [Blender Command Line Arguments](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/command_line/arguments.html)