# Selecting card in blender request?

Tags: linux, opencl, blender

I need to include a list of GPUs to be used for a specific render job. I have determined that all cards have major/minor `/dev/dri/*` files assigned. They have linux `/dev/names` as follows:

```
card0  card1  card2  card3  
renderD128  renderD129  renderD130  renderD131
```

How can I include the card selections in the submitted render file ?

Comment: Just for clarification, you're trying to render on a remote machine, the GPUs are properly detected by Blender but you don't know how to activate them (in background mode)?

Comment: No, I have the MASTER and SLAVE setup ok.  I am working on the LINUX kernel driver in hopes of recognizing 6 or more cards beyond the 4 cards that are presently recognized.

Comment: I am experienced Linux developer having written many drivers over my 30+ years as *nix developer.  I would like to have access to any available source to modify the kernel drivers to talk CL (or directly) with the GPU cards.

Comment: I have hundreds of GPU cards and motherboards available. Looking for correct drivers for RX 580 series RADION GPUs for LINUX that will work with blender.

Comment: I'm a bit confused what you're trying to do. You don't have to modify kernel drivers or create your own graphics driver to use multiple GPUs in Blender, it's supported out-of-the-box. Although I only know of ca. 10 GPUs being used at once, not sure if more work as well.

Comment: I need to run but, tomorrow, I will post the devices with their names, path(s) and major/minor designations.

Comment: I would start with what blender tells you, the [script here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57695293/2684771) shows how to look at the devices seen by cycles. If you are trying to run multiple instances on one machine and choosing different cards for each, sort them and use specific indices for each blender instance. You can [pass cli args to a python script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/6817/935) when starting blender.